# Как реализовать отображение входящих сообщений?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите возможно ли в `ToolBar` справа реализовать иконку входящих сообщений с отображением количества?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так чтоб получилось...

Я просто не представляю как можно сделать, чтоб текстовое поле заходило на изображение...

Скажите это вообще реально?

Comment: Есть [очень много готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+badge), реализующих данную функцию. Есть мнение, что [ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) среди них лучшая - "вешает" бейдж на любое View

Answer (score 1):

Добавить кастомную вьюху в Toolbar

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);
toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
```

Comment: а как задать расположение этого вью элемента?